# MUI autocomplete: how to clear value when options change?

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete

I have a react component that uses MUI Autocomplete for a search input. The options are provided by the parent component as props. It works fine, but the problem is that the options might change at any time - and if the value of the autocomplete is a value that is no longer among the changed options, a warning stating "MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.None of the options match with `"apple"`.You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test." is  spammed to console.

I understand why the warning is displayed. But what I would like to do it this situation is to somehow programmatically clear the autocomplete - so essentially I want to call the same function that gets called when the user presses the built-in clear button of the Autocomplete control. But this does not seem possible!

What would be the best option around this problem?

Here is my component:

```
const FooSearch = (props: { onSearch: (searchedValue: string) => void, options: string[] }) => {
  const { onSearch, options } = props;

  const handleSearch = (val: string | null) => {

    if (val) {
      onSearch(val);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Box width='200px' sx={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, margin: '4px 0px', left: '50px' }}>
      <Autocomplete
        options={options}
        noOptionsText={'No items to display'}
        renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} size='small' InputProps={{
          ...params.InputProps,
          startAdornment: <SearchIcon />,
        }} />}
        getOptionLabel={(option: string) => option}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
          if (options.includes(value))
            return option === value
          else {
            console.log('current value is not anymore in options -> clear value, but how?!')
            return false;
          }
        }}
        clearOnEscape={true}
        onChange={(_event: any, newValue: string | null) => { handleSearch(newValue) }}
      />
    </Box>
  )
}
export default FooSearch;
```

So to reproduce the issue: I pass some values as options from parent. Then select one of the options. Now I modify the passed options by removing the selected option. Then the issue arises.

As you can see, in isOptionEqualToValue I am checking if the current value of the Autocomplete is one of the options and then returning true/false - but if the current value is not anymore in the options (because the options have changed since the selection), I would need to clear the selection.

There does not seem to be a callable clear function in Autocomplete (even though it does have the capability, since theres a built-in button for it!). Seems like a design flaw in Autocomplete.

See the problem in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-wozniak-v4vsvn?file=/src/FooSearch.tsx

Comment: For future reference: I was able to solve this with a hacky solution - store the value of the Autocomplete in state and then on every render do

  if (value && !options.includes(value)) {
    setValue(null);
  }

A bit clumsy.. In my opinion, the Autocomplete should have better tools to handle this quite common situation, where the selected value is all of a sudden not among the options anymore